# Help with this easy lemma of linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to demonstrate a theorem of linear algebra and I need to prove this lemma to finish the proof:

> Let $A=(a_{ij})$ be the matrix representation $T:V\to V$ in the orthonormal basis
>   $\{u_i\}$, then $a_{ij}=\langle T(u_i),u_j\rangle$.

I don't know even how to begin, any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: @Jack sorry, is it ok now?

Comment: it makes sense now `:)`

Answer (score 3):

We have

$$\langle T(u_i),u_j\rangle=(Au_i)^Tu_j=u_i^TA^Tu_j=u_i^T\sum_{k=1}^na^T_{kj}u_k=u_i^T\sum_{k=1}^na_{jk}u_k=a_{ji}$$

Comment: Your solution seems fine but to prove the lemma you are using a particular kind of inner product.

Comment: The lemma is supposed to be proved using general properties of inner products.

Comment: What's this particular kind of inner product?

Comment: $\langle t(u_i),u_j\rangle=(Au_i)^Tu_j$

Comment: This last equality is true whenever we work with an orthonormal basis.

Comment: It's true, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Why $u_i^TA^Tu_j=u_i^T\sum_{k=1}^na^T_{kj}u_k$?